# Unicode error from pip install

Tags: windows, python-2.7, unicode, pip

I am trying to install pyevolve module using pip with command:

pip install pyevolve

And get an error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

The only similar question I found is the following:

[pip install UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036897/pip-install-unicodedecodeerror)

Unfortumately, cannot understand how to use the answer.. Can anyone help me out here please?

System:
Windows 7 64 bit
Anaconda-2.2.0-Windows-x86_64

Comment: Try updating pip to the latest version. I don't know the conda package manager, but just using pip the command is `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Didn't work. Got the same error.

Comment: Does your username have non-ASCII characters? I know some of the bugs related to non-ASCII paths are fixed in the latest pip (7.x). But if you're still having problems you'll have to look for an [existing issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues) to see whether there's a patch, or submit a new issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Finally instruction for all other users like me: if there is no patch for pip or you use some specific version, just check that both your system login and name of your computer only contain english letters. Worked for me.

Comment: For the people that arrives here using google or whatever... In my case, [changing the cmd.exe terminal to UTF-8 did the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line/388500#388500)