# Installing parallel-ssh on python2.7

Tags: python, ssh, pssh

I am trying to install `parallel-ssh` on `python2.7`. My use-case for using this is to make an `ssh` connection run in parallel and not let it block further execution of a `python` file. I used the following command,

```
pip install parallel-ssh
```

But, I am getting the following error,

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried searching for ways to rectify this. I am not very clear on what to do and need some guidance regarding the same.

Comment: this is the error while installing parallel-ssh or while using it?

Comment: This error is while installing `parallel-ssh`.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the parallel-ssh package. Seems to be a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036897/pip-install-unicodedecodeerror. Can you please check?

Comment: @SilentMonk Will check and get back.

Comment: @SilentMonk yes... it was a problem with pip... it installed perfectly after upgrading my pip version... thank you...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue with old versions of pip.

```
pip install -U pip
pip install parallel-ssh
```

This will update pip and then parallel-ssh installation can proceed.