# On every pip module I try to install, it returns this error

Tags: python-3.x, pip

On every pip module I try to install, it returns this error: https://hastebin.com/ozayatequz
This all started a few months ago, I don't know why.

Comment: that might just be a failed python installation . Can you try it in another machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036897/pip-install-unicodedecodeerror)

Comment: No, it started a few months ago- I don't know the cause